# Do I have to modify CMakeLists.txt for a python node?

Tags: ros-kinetic, ubuntu, cmake, ubuntu-xenial

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I try to write a python node running in my package. Before I run catkin_make and rosrun, do I have to modify my CMakeLists.txt file as we did in the case of C++ node it the [tutorial at Step 3](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/WritingPublisherSubscriber%28c%2B%2B%29#roscpp_tutorials.2BAC8-Tutorials.2BAC8-WritingPublisherSubscriber.Building_your_nodes)?

I am new in ROS, I use ubuntu 16.04, ROS kinetic and python 2.7

Thanks in advance!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/306236/do-i-have-to-modify-cmakelists.txt-for-a-python-node?/) by [Spyros](https://answers.ros.org/users/35598/spyros/) on ROS Answers with karma: 51 on 2018-10-19

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You are referring to a tutorial with `roscpp`, there is the same one using `rospy` [here](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/WritingPublisherSubscriber%28python%29).

You have to modify the `CmakeLists.txt` in `python` too but not as systematically as with `roscpp`.
In python if you want to run a simple node with no dependencies you just have to make sure to use the command `chmod +x your_node.py` to get an executable that `rosrun` can use.
In cpp, whenever you create a node you have to create the executable from the `CMakeLists.txt` like that (taken from your tutorial) :

```
add_executable(talker src/talker.cpp)
```

You don't need to do that in python.

But you will have to modify the `CMakeList` if you want to create a custom message, to use a client/server and to list all the dependencies of your package.

---

Originally posted by [Delb](https://answers.ros.org/users/33811/delb/) with karma: 3907 on 2018-10-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Spyros](https://answers.ros.org/users/35598/spyros/) on 2018-10-19**:
@Delb you are right about my tutorial reference. I read the rospy tutorial but I wasn't sure if it takes the CMakeLists.txt modification as default from the previous tutorial (roscpp).In case I want to create a custom message, client/server, list dependencies, I have follow the same steps as roscpp?

**Comment by [Delb](https://answers.ros.org/users/33811/delb/) on 2018-10-19**:
If you follow all the links from the python tutorial I gave you 'll end up [creating Msg and Srv](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/CreatingMsgAndSrv#Creating_a_srv) directly to the configuration of the `CMakeLists.txt`so yes.

**Comment by [Delb](https://answers.ros.org/users/33811/delb/) on 2018-10-19**:
One piece of advice when you are wondering those things : try, experience yourself. If you don't change the `CMakeLists.txt` you'll direclty see error messages if it had to be changed.

**Comment by [Spyros](https://answers.ros.org/users/35598/spyros/) on 2018-10-19**:
Thank you! Your answer helped me to understand what I have to do.